# knockout does not work when data contains <script>

Tags: knockout.js

I have following knockout definition:

```
FunctionVm = function (initialData) {

var self = this;

self.Dto = {
    Name: ko.observable(initialData.Dto.Name)
    };
};
```

The Html is simple:

```
<input data-bind="value:Dto.Name" id="Dto_Name" type="text"></input>
```

And I called knockout like this:

```
    var initialData = ...
var functionVm = new FunctionVm(initialData);
ko.applyBindings(functionVm);
```

Now, if the initialData = {"Dto":{"Name":"Home's"}}; it is OK.

However if

```
   initialData = {"Dto":{"Name":"<script>alert(1)</script>"}};
```

the knockout does not display anything at all.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 2):

That's because the `</script>` ending tag ends the script tag that contains the code, so you get a syntax error because of the unterminated string literal.

Break up the tag into two strings:

```
initialData = {"Dto":{"Name":"<script>alert(1)</scr"+"ipt>"}};
```

Comment: I am using C# to generate the client side. How can I split the string?
Eg: using Newtonsoft.Json to serialize it to json.

Comment: @user2103886: Split it after serialising, e.g.:  `str = str.Replace("</script>", "</scr\"+\"ipt>");`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you validate the data by escaping the HTML before inserting it into "Name"?  PHP and jQuery both have functions for this task.  Don't trust user input :)